# Kafka Consumer Setting for avoiding High CPU

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

We are having Camel Kafka consumer (camel-kafka:2.23.1) to read message from Kafka. The default settings work well for daytime,However nightly there is Bulk load of messages 5000 Message per second and we are seeing high CPU, wanted to know are there any settings in Kafka Consumer/Camel Kafka to reduce high CPU usage?Do other face a similar issue

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the consumer as a service (systemd) on the OS?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I am running as a Camel Spring boot application running in docker container in kubernetes.